# C# - Supply ViewModel from JSON string result

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, json.net

Good day,

I need a help in extracting JSON string and supply it on my view model.

In my example, I have a ViewModel that has 2 classes.

Classes:

```
public class Student {
    public int StudentId {get;set;}
    public string Firstname {get;set;}
    public string Lastname {get;set;}
}

public class Address {
    public int AddressId {get;set;}
    public string Street {get;set;}
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class StudentAddressViewModel{
    public Student Student {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get;set}
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IFormCollection studentInfo){
    // wherein studentInfo is the key
    ...
}
```

In my controller, I'm sending this JSON string.

```
{[studentInfo,{"Student":{"firstname":"Johhny","lastname":"Bravo"},"Address":{"street":"New york street..."}])
```

I'm trying this:

```
var studentInfo = studentInfo["studentInfo"];

var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(studentInfo);

var studentVm = new StudentAddressViewModel{
    new Student{
        Firstname: value["firstname"], Lastname: value["lastname"]
    },
    new Address{
        Address: value["address"]
    }
}
```

But I'm having a null `value`.

Any help, please?

Comment: You have to provide more info like what you have written on Controller side that return that Json and where you supplied your sample code.

Comment: The JSON you have is not valid. Also what do you mean by webview and where are you sending it?

Comment: Are you getting this format of json? {[studentInfo,{"Student":{"firstname":"Johhny","lastname":"Bravo"},"Address":{"street":"New york street..."}])

Comment: Yes @NoorAllSafaet

Comment: that's what I'm getting @NoorAllSafaet

Comment: The opening `{` doesn't match the closing `)` in your JSON. Isn't that a problem? Also, how is `studentInfo` a valid array element in JSON? It's not a Javascript primitive, and it's not a string. Seems like a big error. And finally, if `{`at the beginning starts an object, where is the key and where is the value? I understand that this may not be a true JSON object all the way to the outside, but you said that it is. Your question otherwise simply does NOT have enough information to answer it. Where is this JSON string coming from? What on earth is `studentInfo = studentInfo["studentInfo"];`?

Comment: From my controller, the `studentInfo` is the `key` @ErikE

Comment: @ErikE I updated my question and provided my controller

Comment: Why can't your controller be `public async Task<IActionResult> Create(StudentAddressViewModel studentInfo) {` and you use model binding to get the list already hydrated by ASP.Net itself?

Comment: Can you also please provide the code for the the HTML form that is posting to your controller action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to supply directly your ViewModel in your `DeserializeObject` instead of Dictionary.

```
var studentInfo = studentInfo["studentInfo"];
var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StudentAddressViewModel>(studentInfo);
```

Then call each model directly.

```
var studentVm = new StudentAddressViewModel{
    Student = value.Student,
    Address = value.Address
}
```

I hope this helps others as well.